# 'readpage' overrides nothing from udacity tutorial

Tags: kotlin

When I run the following codes, I get an alert 'readpage' overrides nothing in line 42, the `override fun readpage()` in class eBook. Why is that and how do I fix this?
I am learning kotlin and following a [tutorial from udacity](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud9011/lessons/77b7bbc2-3cf4-4e01-b03e-455b36cb9ced/concepts/a30e2c80-ed37-4c00-b24a-54c11a1480d2). I have tried to figure this out by myself for 2 weeks and spending 10+ hours but still don't know why?

```kotlin
package Aquarium

fun main(args: Array<String> ) {
    delegation()
}
fun delegation(){
    val pleco=Plecotomus()
    println("Fish has color ${pleco.color}")
    pleco.eat()
}
interface FishAction{
    fun eat()
}
interface FishColor{
    val color:String
}
class Plecotomus(fishcolor:FishColor=GoldColor):
        FishAction by PrintingFishAction(food="eat munch algae"),
        FishColor by fishcolor

object GoldColor:FishColor{
    override val color="gold"
}
object RedColor:FishColor{
    override val color="red"
}
class PrintingFishAction(val food:String):FishAction{
    override fun eat(){
        println(food)
    }
}

open class Book(val title:String, val author:String){
    private var currentPage=1
    open fun readPage(){
        currentPage++
    }
}

class eBook(title:String,author:String,var format:String="text"){
    private var wordsCount=0
    override fun readPage(){
        wordsCount=wordsCount+250
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

add :Book(title, author) after class eBook() => class eBook() :Book(title, author){} will solve the problem.

class eBook(title:String,author:String,var format:String="text"):Book(title, author){private var wordsCount=0
override fun readPage(){
wordsCount=wordsCount+250} }

Answer (score 1):

This class

```kotlin
class eBook(val title:String, val author:String, val format:String="text"){
    private var wordsCount=0
    override fun readPage() {
        wordsCount=wordsCount+250
    }
}
```

does not inherit from anything. But you are trying to `override` the function `readPage`. Since there is nothing to override, the compiler gives you the error

> 'readPage' overrides nothing

Please remove the keyword `override` and you'll be able to compile the code.

```kotlin
class eBook(title:String,author:String,var format:String="text"){
    private var wordsCount=0
    fun readPage(){
        wordsCount=wordsCount+250
    }
}
```

**Note**: Function `eBook` is not used anywhere. But as you're learning to code, take your time exploring and making mistakes.

Comment: ```open class Book(val title:String, val author:String){
    private var currentPage=1
    open fun readPage(){
        currentPage++
    }
}``` The tutorial has open fun readPage() in class Book so it override fun readPage() in class eBook so readPage() has used before and that's what the tutorial is showing the students how to override. Isn't it true?

Comment: @LisaBaron You overside something when you've inherited from a super class or abstract class or interface. Here your class `eBook` does not inherit from anything. Please refer to [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inheritance.html) doc to have a good glace how the inheritance syntax looks like.